# PHP fopen file not writable even after chmod set to 0777, Linux Server issue

Tags: php, apache, fopen, chmod, permission-denied

Here is my simple code

```
$dst = "otps/hello.txt";
echo $dst, file_exists($dst) ? ' exists' : ' does not exist', "\n";
echo $dst, is_readable($dst) ? ' is readable' : ' is NOT readable', "\n";
echo $dst, is_writable($dst) ? ' is writable' : ' is NOT writable', "\n";
$fh = fopen($dst, 'w');
if ( !$fh ) {
    echo ' last error: ';
    echo '<pre>';print_r(error_get_last());echo'</pre>';
}
```

My current directory is set to 0777 but still the error, I created file manually and set permission to 0777 and still the same error.

[image]

[image]

here is output

[image]

Please note, I have setup my VPS server myself on digital ocean. I tried changing chown of the whole directories and files to `apache, root, nobody` but nothing is working.

Comment: Is the volume the file is on writable?  Are there any ACLs on the file/directory/volume?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean, I created file manually from ssh, thats mean volume is writable !!!

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the file just to test.

Comment: @WasimA.:  My suggestions are covering all the bases for writable permission.  Besides the individual file's *mode*, there are several other layers:  a volume can be mounted readonly.  Also most operating systems allow using an access control list which is a security control feature.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list

Answer (score 0):

running command

```
setenforce 0
```

works for me, not sure why :)